# How to view exceptions in Seq

Tags: seq

I have configured [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq) for my local Sitecore instance.

1. After an error is logged, it takes around 3 mins to show up in Seq. Can we configure it to display real-time.
2. I do not see the exception & stack trace as shown in snap. What needs to be configured to view them.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Reference: https://himadritechblog.wordpress.com/2020/11/14/serilog-appender-for-sitecore-logging/

After installing & setting up `Seq`, I have configured its API key & Host URL in my instance's webconfig

I have also configured Serilog appender like this. That is why I'm able to see all the logs. But just not the exception details.

**Foundation.Logging.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:security="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/security/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentDelivery or ContentManagement">
    <log4net>
      <appender name="SerilogAppender" type="Foundation.Logging.Serilog.SerilogAppender, Foundation.Logging" patch:after = "appender[@name='LogFileAppender']">
        <minimumlevel value="DEBUG" />        
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" />
        <encoding value="utf-8" />
      </appender>
      <root>
        <appender-ref ref="SerilogAppender" patch:after = "*[@ref='LogFileAppender']"/>
      </root>
    </log4net>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**SerilogAppender.cs**

```
using global::Serilog;
using global::Serilog.Core;
using global::Serilog.Events;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.helpers;
using log4net.spi;
using System;
using System.Configuration;

public class SerilogAppender : BufferingAppenderSkeleton
    {
        private string _minimumLevel;
        
        public string MinimumLevel
        {
            get => this._minimumLevel;
            set => this._minimumLevel = value;
        }

        public string ApiKey
        {
            //get => _apiKey;
            //set => _apiKey = value;
            get
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SeqApiKey"];
            }
        }

        public string SeqHost
        {
            //get => _seqHost;
            //set => _seqHost = value;
            get
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SeqHostUrl"];
            }
        }

        [Obsolete("Use the BufferingAppenderSkeleton Fix methods")]
        public bool LocationInfo
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
            set
            {
            }
        }

        protected override void SendBuffer(LoggingEvent[] events)
        {
            using (var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(new LoggingLevelSwitch(GetLogEventLevel()))
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
                .Enrich.WithProcessId()
                .Enrich.WithProcessName()
                .Enrich.WithProperty("ThreadId", SystemInfo.CurrentThreadId)
                .Enrich.WithMemoryUsage()
                .WriteTo.Seq(SeqHost, apiKey: ApiKey)
                .CreateLogger())
            {
                foreach (var thisEvent in events)
                {
                    LogEvent(log, thisEvent);
                }
            }

        }

        protected override bool RequiresLayout => true;

        private void LogEvent(Logger log, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            try
            {
                if (loggingEvent.Level == Level.DEBUG)
                {
                    log.Debug(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);
                }
                if (loggingEvent.Level == Level.INFO)
                {
                    log.Information(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);
                }
                if (loggingEvent.Level == Level.WARN)
                {
                    log.Warning(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);
                }
                if (loggingEvent.Level == Level.ERROR)
                {
                    log.Error(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);
                }
                if (loggingEvent.Level == Level.FATAL)
                {
                    log.Fatal(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.ErrorHandler.Error("Error occurred while logging the event.", ex);
            }
        }
        private LogEventLevel GetLogEventLevel()
        {
            var logEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Debug;
            switch (MinimumLevel.ToLower())
            {
                case "debug":
                    logEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Debug;
                    break;
                case "info":
                    logEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Information;
                    break;
                case "warn":
                    logEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Warning;
                    break;
                case "error":
                    logEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Error;
                    break;
                case "fatal":
                    logEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Fatal;
                    break;
            }

            return logEventLevel;
        }
    }
```

Comment: These questions are unique to Seq and would require knowledge of that product documentation. What have you tried after having read the docs?

Comment: @MichaelWest I'm new to Seq and following the doc, I have set it up. Then I have added its API key & host url in my instance's web.config. Also added the Serilog appender patch & class that I have now updated in my question.

Answer (score 1):

The version of **log4net** included with Sitecore should have a method on the `LoggingEvent` specifically for getting the exception error string.

When logging you should use both the `RenderedMessage` and `GetExceptionStrRep()`.

Comment: That worked. But I'm able to add it only in the Title i.e. the whole exception shows beside "STRATUM_ERROR". How can we add it in the collapsible section. `msg.AppendLine(loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);                     msg.AppendLine(loggingEvent.GetExceptionStrRep());                     log.Error(msg.ToString());`

Answer (score 1):

It's a better approach to format the event log message, as you're using `layout`:

```xml
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" />
```

This layout can format the message for your. So then you can use default method:

```
// instead of loggingEvent.RenderedMessage
// instead of loggingEvent.GetExceptionStrRep()
string message = RenderLoggingEvent(loggingEvent);
```

the final code is this:

```
public class SerilogAppender : BufferingAppenderSkeleton
{
    public string MinimumLevel { get; set; }

    public string ApiKey { get; set; }

    public string SeqHost { get; set; }
    
    [Obsolete("Use the BufferingAppenderSkeleton Fix methods")]
    public bool LocationInfo => false;

    protected override void SendBuffer(LoggingEvent[] events)
    {
        using (var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(new LoggingLevelSwitch(GetLogEventLevel(MinimumLevel, LogEventLevel.Information)))
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithMachineName()
            .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
            .Enrich.WithProcessId()
            .Enrich.WithProcessName()
            .Enrich.WithProperty("ThreadId", SystemInfo.CurrentThreadId)
            .Enrich.WithProperty("Site", GetSite())
            .Enrich.WithMemoryUsage()
            .WriteTo.Seq(SeqHost, apiKey: ApiKey)
            .CreateLogger())
        {
            foreach (var thisEvent in events)
            {
                LogEvent(log, thisEvent);
            }
        }
    }

    private static string GetSite()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Sitecore.Context.Site?.Name) ? Sitecore.Context.Site.Name : null;
    }

    protected override bool RequiresLayout => true;

    private void LogEvent(ILogger log, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        try
        {
            // key change
            var message = RenderLoggingEvent(loggingEvent);
            var level = GetLogEventLevel(loggingEvent.Level.ToString());
            log.Write(level, message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorHandler.Error("Error occurred while logging the event.", ex);
        }
    }

    private static LogEventLevel GetLogEventLevel(string level, LogEventLevel defaultValue = LogEventLevel.Debug)
    {
        var logEventLevel = defaultValue;
        switch (level.ToLowerInvariant())
        {
            case "debug":
                logEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Debug;
                break;
            case "info":
                logEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Information;
                break;
            case "warn":
                logEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Warning;
                break;
            case "error":
                logEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Error;
                break;
            case "fatal":
                logEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Fatal;
                break;
        }

        return logEventLevel;
    }
}
```

*Note*.You can control `bufferSize` for local (or any) environment to make log messages appear in SEQ really quickly (instead only when 512 messages are logged they will be sent):

```xml
<appender name="SerilogAppender" type="[YOUR_NAMESPACE].SerilogAppender, [YOUR_DLL]"
          patch:after="appender[@name='LogFileAppender']">
  <minimumlevel value="INFO" />
  <apikey value="$(env:SEQ_API_KEY)" />
  <seqhost value="$(env:SEQ_URL)" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" />
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
  <bufferSize value="10" /> <!-- HERE you can set your buffer size value (default is 512) -->
</appender>
```

or using config transformation:

```xml
<log4net>
  <appender name="SerilogAppender" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
    <bufferSize value="10" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
  </appender>
</log4net>
```